# background image doesn´t show, link ok, selector ok, is there any interference I don´t realize?

Tags: html, css, image, background

I want to create 2 buttons with a sprite-img as background. But the image doesn´t show up.

Maybe there is an interference with background css of the grid?

The document structure is like this:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">     // this has a background color that seems not to affect 
    <div class="row">         // this has no background
      <div class="column">    // this has a background color that seems to affect
        <div class="wrapper-for-buttons">  // here are the divs for th background image
         <div class="I-want-a-BG-image">   // here shall the background image go
```

What I have tried:
I´ve checked the image URL with  in the very same html page. This works.
I´ve checked the html code and css in another (clean) html document. This works, too.

I have a very specific selector for the different cols as they change background colors on other pages.
But: I´ve checked the selector of the div that shall get the background-image in the very same html page with making a ´border´ and a ´background-color´. This works.

So I don´t know where to search anymore…
Any hints are very appreciated.
Thanks in Advance

CSS

```
.container {
  display: block;
  width: 95%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #0F0;
}
/* Does this selector make trouble? */
[class|="col"] {
  float: left;
   min-height: 1px;
   background-color: #F0F;
}

#testImage {
display: block;
position: relative;
float:left;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background: url("./src/img/contact/mailphone.png") 0 0;
border: 5px solid green;
}
```

HTML

```
   <address id="imprint">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row clearfix">
          <div class="col-70">
            <p>this col is not of interest</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-30">
            <div class="mailphonewrapper">
              <div id="testImage"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </address>
```

Comment: Are you sure that your image path is correct? https://codepen.io/studiospindle/pen/bGGOLWa

Comment: Learn to use your browser dev tools to debug issues like this. Inspect the element to check if the CSS rules you think should apply, actually apply to the element in question - and if they maybe get overwritten by something else. Go check the error console to see if there are any messages regarding the image URL, such as a 404.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Of course I checked with Google Inspector first. GI shows the image URL on the element page and it is not crossed out. And Yes the path is correct. I´ll search on. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Solved. Thanks to both answers. The path was correct for html page.  I have relative paths and forgot to take the starting point css. In Element View  Google Inspector showed me the image, but not in console view.